# Selecting certain days in a date range

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, date-range

I have the query below which gives me the number of days that a student was absent. DATEDIFF and DATEPART calculate the weekdays and holidays should not be counted as an absent day. The absent days stored in studentTable in two fields which are fromDate and toDate. So the absent days are in a date range. If a student is one day absent, it is recorded 11/23/2015, 11/23/2015. If a student is two days absent ,then 11/23/2015, 11/24/2015.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE SET @startDate = '20151121'
DECLARE @endDate DATE SET @endDate = '20151123'       

SELECT      
  a.studentName

  ,SUM(DATEDIFF(dd, fromDate, toDate) 
  - (DATEDIFF(wk, fromDate, toDate) * 2) 
  -CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, fromDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
  +CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, toDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 1 )- COUNT(h.holiday)
   AS totalAbsentDay        

  FROM studentTable a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN holiday h 
ON h.holiday < a.toDate and h.holiday > a.fromDate

WHERE a.fromDate = @startDate AND a.toDate = @endDate
GROUP BY a.studentName
```

The problem here is that when I try to declare a start and an end date, it does not give me the correct absent days. 
For example, if a student is absent between 11/23/2015  and 11/26/2015 which is 4 days absent , and I declare start date 11/22/2015 and end date 11/27/2015, the query doesn’t give me the result of 3.

Comment: Are you sure  `WHERE a.fromDate = @startDate AND a.toDate = @endDate` is the correct filter..? I mean if the filter commented out, the result is correct?

Comment: Yes, Susilo. if you comment out DECLARE parts and WHERE clause. Query works fine.

Comment: I tried with my own data based my own perception..it's turn out even after `declare` and `where` commented out your query fails if there is multiple holiday within a student absent..may be my perception is wrong..so please can you share the table structure and sample data..?

Comment: I have double checked and it works after commenting out  declare and where.

Comment: Still need table structure and sample data..

Comment: I am working on a sample data. I will share as soon as I finish.

Comment: CREATE TABLE studentTable
    ([studentName] varchar(13), [fromDate] date, [toDate] date)
;
    
INSERT INTO studentTable
    ([studentName], [fromDate], [toDate])
VALUES
    ('John A.', '20160212', '20160212'),  
    ('Sue K.', '20160212', '20160217')   
;

CREATE TABLE holiday
     ([holiday] date);
INSERT INTO holiday
     ([holiday])
VALUES 
     ('20160215');

Comment: I have tried this and it works. John A has one day absent. Sue K has 3 days(20160212, 20160216 and 20160217) absent because 20160213 and 20160214 were weekends ans 20160215 was holiday.

Comment: Believe me its fail for `Sue K.` if you add `20160216` as holiday..but never mind..i working on my answer now..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103663/discussion-between-susilo-and-ncooper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query below will work for given database scheme, may not the best solution because use three level of queries

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE SET @startDate = '2016-02-05'
DECLARE @endDate DATE SET @endDate = '2016-02-20'       

SELECT
    studentName,
    SUM(AbsentDay) totalAbsentDay
FROM
(
    SELECT      
      a.studentName
      ,DATEDIFF(dd, fromDate, toDate) 
      - (DATEDIFF(wk, fromDate, toDate) * 2) 
      -CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, fromDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
      +CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, toDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 1 - COUNT(h.holiday)
       AS AbsentDay        
      FROM (
            SELECT
                studentName,-- Name,
                CASE WHEN fromDate<@startDate THEN @startDate ELSE fromDate END fromDate,
                CASE WHEN toDate>@endDate THEN @endDate ELSE toDate END toDate
            FROM 
                StudentTable S
            WHERE 
                S.toDate >= @startDate AND s.fromDate <= @endDate
        ) a 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN holiday h 
        ON h.holiday < a.toDate and h.holiday > a.fromDate

    GROUP BY studentName, fromDate, toDate
) B
GROUP BY studentName
```

For easier query and faster execution please consider to redesign `studentTable` to something like `idStudent`, `AbsentDate`..just a suggestion..